# Induction motor

Tags: power, induction-motor

Will induction motor draw more power at low speed ?

Comment: Is this a photo shoot? The question is valid but the pictures are confusing at best. Please focus on the motor under question. Diagrams are ok as well.

Answer (score 3):

An induction motor at low speed should not draw more power, but when full voltage is initially applied, it will draw a very high current. It will also draw a very high current if it is stalled or nearly stalled by a mechanical overload. The power will not increase proportionally under those those conditions because the power factor is very low. However the power may increase above the rated power of the motor. If the motor remains stalled it will overheat quite quickly because all of the input power is dissipated as heat in the motor.

If the motor speed is reduced by a speed controller, it should not draw either high current or high power if the speed control method is appropriate for the motor and load.

If the motor speed is reduced by reducing the applied voltage, the input power will not increase, but the motor may overheat because a higher percentage of the input power is dissipated as heat in the motor. This type of control is normally used only for fans and centrifugal pumps. With that type of load, the input power to the motor is reduced by reducing the speed.

If the motor speed, with any type of load, is reduced using a variable frequency drive (VFD), the input power to the motor is directly proportional the mechanical power delivered to the load by the motor. There may be some increase in motor losses with reduced speed, but that increase can be held quite low by a good VFD design.

Comment: It seems you just considered power required to drive the load, increased current increases copper losses and in that sense motor obviously draws more power.

Comment: @Deep I was considering speed reduction with a fully loaded motor, but I did not consider the copper losses carefully enough. Depending on the locked-rotor current, the locked-rotor power is likely to be at or above the full-load power. I revised my answer.